# Почему пропадает textarea?

Tags: php, html, html5

У меня проблема, у меня почему то время от времени на сайте пропадает textarea.
Вот скрин, в коде он есть, а на странице нету, в чём проблема?
[image: ml]
Вот код

```
            <form action="/code.php" method="POST">
            <tеxtarea  contenteditable="true" style="width:100%;height:150px;" name="text" placeholder="Текст поста" required><?php echo $_SESSION['post_edit']; ?></tеxtarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="idd" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['post_edit_id']; ?>">
            <button name="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['post_edit']))echo 'edit_post_yes'; else echo 'add_post'; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['post_edit']))echo 'Изменить'; else echo 'Добавить'; ?></button>
            </form>
```

Использую php в коде

Comment: Прикладывайте код текстом, а не картинкой. Проблемы могут быть в css

Comment: Да дело то не в css, я просто вообще не применяю css к textarea

Comment: ну может из-за bootstrap 4

Comment: У вас буква `е` (русская) вместо буквы `e` (английская) в слове `textarea`

Comment: я не знаю что к чему, но когда я ввожу через клавиатуру textarea, он делает русскую e, я просто в редакторе выбрал подсказку и всё норм. Спасибо большое. Блин это просто ультра мега глупая ошибка

Answer (score 1):

У вас буква е (русская) вместо буквы e (английская) в слове textarea – ArchDemon